# Cocos2d-x tv noise effect

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, cocos2d-x

I'm creating a game using cocos2dx version 2. I'm trying to add some effect that I can't figure out how to implement. The effect I'm trying to add is a TV noise effect. How can I do this using cocos2d-x?

Comment: Shader + Post-Processing + FBO = TV Noise Effect!

Comment: Start with a fragment shader: http://indiestack.com/2013/09/static-analysis/ and blend that with your scene as necessary.